# GORM golang SQL query to do a case-insensitive search is not working

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I want to do a case-insensitive search in Golang. I am using [this](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm@v1.23.6) library.

I have tried the following but its not working.

```
someId = "abc"
model := abcModel{Id: someId}
result := p.db.Where("lower(id) = lower(?)", someId).Take(&model)
```

> Id is primary-key here

I have also tried

```
db.Where("LOWER(id) LIKE LOWER(?)", fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", someId)).Take(&model)
```

Could someone please help here. Not sure whats going wrong. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

***EDIT***:

This is what I have in DB

```
         id      |          created_at           |          updated_at           | deleted_at |  client_id | ttl  |             client_type              |    token  |          expires_on          
--------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+
        ABC      | 2023-10-30 16:10:59.614132+00 | 2023-10-30 16:10:59.614132+00 |            |  ae30e377  | 100  | 7da0e618-7393-45c2-94dc-5e7b1d6c1610 |   abc     | 2023-10-30 16:27:39.613566+00
```

and I was hoping that above query would return this record in DB since its a case-insensitive search.

The error that I am getting is `record not found`
https://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html#ErrRecordNotFound

I am running Postgres server in a docker container.
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: How exactly is it *not working*? Can you show sample/mock records you expect this to find in the db and what you're getting instead, or error message?

Comment: Hi @Zegarek, updated the question with more info. Apologies for not adding this earlier. Thanks.

Comment: can you lowercase `someId` in Go, and then use `LOWER(id) LIKE ?` instead of `LOWER(id) LIKE LOWER(?)`

Comment: I tried that as well using `strings.ToLower()` in go. Still didn't work.

Comment: what is `p` supposed to be?

Comment: Its nothing. just a wrapper

```type Postgres struct {
 db gorm.DB
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what `p` represents, but here is a working example using both `Take()` and `Where().Take()`:

```
func main() {
    // open connection to postgres
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(...), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    // Get the row
    someId := "abc"
    var result abcModel
    db.Take(&result, "lower(id) = lower(?)", someId)
    // Print the row
    fmt.Println(result)

    // Find the row using Where
    var result2 abcModel
    db.Where("lower(id) = lower(?)", someId).Take(&result2)
    // Print the row
    fmt.Println(result2)

}
```

Output:

```
$ go run .
{ABC 2023-10-30 10:00:57.774905 -0700 PDT 2023-10-30 10:00:57.774905 -0700 PDT <nil> ae30e377 100 7da0e618-7393-45c2-94dc-5e7b1d6c1610 abc 2023-10-30 10:00:57.774906 -0700 PDT}
{ABC 2023-10-30 10:00:57.774905 -0700 PDT 2023-10-30 10:00:57.774905 -0700 PDT <nil> ae30e377 100 7da0e618-7393-45c2-94dc-5e7b1d6c1610 abc 2023-10-30 10:00:57.774906 -0700 PDT}
```

Therefore, your original code seems to work, except that perhaps your error has something to do with how `p` is defined

Comment: so, i realized the mistake I was making. 
I was doing this. (First code snippet I have shared)
`model := abcModel{Id: someId}`

As soon as I did what you were doing, it started working fine.
`var result abcModel`